# JavaScript - Stop redirection without user intervention and get destination URL

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to run some JS in a webpage so I can click elements that will take me to another webpage and do 2 things:

1. Get the destination URL.
2. Stop the redirection.

So far I read about adding an event listener to stop redirection:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // Cancel the event
    e.preventDefault(); // If you prevent default behavior in Mozilla Firefox prompt will always be shown
    // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
    e.returnValue = '';
});
```

but there's always a popup and I cannot figure out the destination address.

### Edit:

I was able to obtain the destination URL from the microservice by intercepting the XMLHttpRequests so the first problem is solved ... redirection is still an issue.

```
const xhrOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
    if (method === "GET") {
        const urlQuery = "some_discrimination_factor";
        const urlPropertyName = "redirection_url";
        if(url.endsWith(urlPropertyName)) {
            this.onload = function(){
                const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                if (response.hasOwnProperty(urlPropertyName)) {
                    console.log(response[urlPropertyName]);
                }
            };
        }
    }
    xhrOpen.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
};
```

Here's the same thing but using DOM Level 2 Events:

```
let xhrListener; //use only to avoid multiple listeners error while debugging
const xhrOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
    if (method === "GET") {
        const urlQuery = "some_discrimination_factor";
        const urlPropertyName = "redirection_url";
        if(url.endsWith(urlPropertyName)) {
            if (xhrListener) { //use only to avoid multiple listeners error while debugging
                this.removeEventListener("readystatechange", xhrListener);
            }
            this.addEventListener("load", function nonAnonymWrap(e){
                xhrListener = nonAnonymWrap;//use only to avoid multiple listeners error while debugging
                const response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                if (response.hasOwnProperty(urlPropertyName)) {
                    console.log(response[urlPropertyName]);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    xhrOpen.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
};
```

Comment: Why not intercept `mousedown` instead?

Comment: `beforeunload` means page close...

Comment: just add listener to element which user may `click`.
writen destination in that element and read it when event has been trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Brad, I would definitely need the destination URL and I don't think I can get that while intercepting `mousedown` on an element like `<a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>`; also I might need to trigger the `onclick` logic.

Comment: @CamelCamelius Where is the URL coming from then?

Comment: @Brad I think the URL might be coming from a microservice

Comment: @CamelCamelius What do you mean, "you think"?  Is this not your webpage?

Comment: dont understant either. you can't stop user leaving page

Comment: So you are saying it is impossible to avoid the redirection and the closest thing available is the code above that in a way says to the user: "Hey, you are about to leave the site. Do you want to stay or you want to leave?"

Comment: If avoiding the redirection is impossible, is there a way to get the destination url at any point in time? Let's say maybe from the `window` object or from an event? Something that does not involve `document.getElementById('#myLink').href` because of the `<a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>` situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ockham's razor:

> Entities should not be multiplied without necessity.

Being new to JavaScript's rabbit hole I started going heavy on XMLHttpRequest but apparently something simpler was sufficient for my case:

```
//backup original function in case redirection is needed later
const windowOpen = window.open;
let isRedirectionEnabled = false;
window.open = function() {
    //destination URL obtained without redirection
    let targetUrl = arguments[0]; 
    console.log(targetUrl);
    if(isRedirectionEnabled) {
        windowOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a href="to_other_page" id="myEle1">CLICK ME</a>
```

```js
var dom = document.getElementById('#myEle1');
dom.addListener('click', function($e){
  $e.preventDefault(); // stop <a> tag behavior
  var url = dom.href; // the url you want
})
```

like this?

Comment: Hi @王仁宏, I would definitely need the destination URL and I don't think I can get that from an element like `<a href="javascript:void(0)">link</a>`; also I might need to trigger the already-available onclick logic.