# Get destination URLs of HTML elements programatically using JavaScript - Java - Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

There's a page with a lot of links pointing everywhere but I cannot get the destination URLs because web addresses seem not to be there in the code which has something like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">
        <span title="Text">Text</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Has tons of obfuscated code. My best guess is that it might be dynamically loading the URLs from a micro service.

Is there a way to programmatically get the destination URLs of elements preferably without navigating to the link? I am trying by using JavaScript / Selenium with Java.

I was thinking that it might be possible by triggering the `onclick` event and getting the URL at some point before redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:

1. Used JavaScript code snippet that redefines the `open()` method of browser's `window` object for obtaining the target URL, store it in the global context and prevent the redirection. [This question might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65867867/javascript-stop-redirection-without-user-intervention-and-get-destination-url).
2. Triggered click on HTML link element to run the underlying XMLHttpRequest call.
3. Using JavaScript's `clearInterval()` and Java's `executeAsyncScript()` methods, watch a global variable until its value is set (value is set by the `window.open()` method after the element is clicked).

Because I was using ChromeDriver, the example below is to be run on Google Chrome

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class DeadLinkTest {

    private static WebDriver driver;
    private static WebDriverWait wait;
    private static JavascriptExecutor js;
    
    private static String driverAbsolutePath = "/chromedriver.exe";
    private static String profileDirectory = "/myprofile";
    //Look for a webpage that actually has elements like <a href='javascript:void(0);'> that causes redirection
    private static String starterUrl = "https://www.google.com/";

    //XPath for an element like <a href='javascript:void(0);'> 
    private static final String DEAD_LINKS_XPATH = "//a[starts-with(translate(normalize-space(@href),' ',''),'javascript:void')]";
    private static final String CLICK_ELEMENT_JS_CODE = "arguments[0].click();";
    private static final String DOCUMENT_READY_JS_CODE = "return document.readyState;";
    private static final String LINK_RESOURCE_URL_VAR_NAME = "window.redirectionUrl"; //global variable name
    private static final String PREPARE_BROWSER_FOR_URL_EXTRACTION_JS_CODE =
            "window.windowOpen = window.open;" + //backup original function
            "window.isRedirectionEnabled = false;" + //turn on/off redirection via global variable
            LINK_RESOURCE_URL_VAR_NAME + " = null;" + 
            "window.open = function() {" + //redifine open() method
            "    " + LINK_RESOURCE_URL_VAR_NAME + " = arguments[0];" + //put link's url into global variable
            "    if(window.isRedirectionEnabled) {" + 
            "        windowOpen.apply(this, arguments);" + 
            "    }" + 
            "};";
    private static final String GET_LINK_RESOURCE_URL_JS_CODE =
            "(function(seleniumCallback){" + //IIFE that recieves selenium's callback function from executeAsyncScript() method
            "    let intervalId = setInterval(function(){" + 
            "        if(" + LINK_RESOURCE_URL_VAR_NAME + ") {" + //check if global variable is still null
            "            clearInterval(intervalId);" + 
            "            let urlString = " + LINK_RESOURCE_URL_VAR_NAME + ";" + 
            "            " + LINK_RESOURCE_URL_VAR_NAME + " = null;" + //set global variable to default state
            "            seleniumCallback(urlString);" + //Send back the url to Java
            "        }" + 
            "    },0);" + 
            "}(arguments[0]));";

    public static ChromeDriver createChromeDriver() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--user-data-dir=" + profileDirectory + "/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Profile 2");
        //options.addArguments("--profile-directory=Profile 2");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        //options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        //options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverAbsolutePath);
        return new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        driver = createChromeDriver();
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        try {
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(starterUrl);
            wait.until(webDriver -> js.executeScript(DOCUMENT_READY_JS_CODE).toString().equals("complete")); //Checks that page is loaded
            
            js.executeScript(PREPARE_BROWSER_FOR_URL_EXTRACTION_JS_CODE); //Avoids redirection and prepares global variable
            WebElement deadLink = driver.findElement(By.xpath(DEAD_LINKS_XPATH));
            try {
                deadLink.click(); //Puts the link url into browser's global variable. See PREPARE_BROWSER_FOR_URL_EXTRACTION_JS_CODE
            } catch (ElementNotInteractableException e) {
                js.executeScript(CLICK_ELEMENT_JS_CODE, deadLink); //In case element is not clickable
            }
            String linkUrl = (String) js.executeAsyncScript(GET_LINK_RESOURCE_URL_JS_CODE);
            System.out.println(String.format("TARGET URL: %s", linkUrl));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```